# How to debug Remix.run apps with node --inspect or webstorm

Tags: remix, remix.run

I want to use chrome to debug or even webstorm, not interested in VSCode which has a solution.

Also using typescript for added complexity

Usually we just need the entry point of remix.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a node.js run configuration with `cli.js` of Remix.

[image: Webstorm configuration for debugging Remix. Javascript file is node_modules/@remix-run/dev/dist/cli.js]